# MVVM Refresh Datagrid from ViewModel even when collection doesn't change

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I'm writing an application to read and analyze some logs my company software uses. There are multiple types of logs, but let's take only two for the purpose of describing my problem. Namely, logs of `TypeA` and `TypeB`. I have designed one class to hold a single line of log data, named `LogLine` which looks like below.

```
public class LogLine
{
    public long LineNum { get; set; }
    public string Msg { get; set; }
}
```

**So here's my problem/requirement.**

In my main `ViewModel`, I'd like to read logs of each type only once when the application loads. Read `TypeA` logs one time, and store in an `ObservableCollection` of `LogLine` instances, do the same for `TypeB`. Then depending on my choice the `DataGrid` displays logs from one type, and if I click a button at any time, the same `DataGrid` should display logs from the other type. Note that my logs data doesn't change, I simply want to display my choice of logs.

For this I created three classes, namely, `ControllerMain`, `ControllerA`, and `ControllerB`. The last two derive from the former like so:

```
public class ControllerMain
{
    public ControllerMain()
    {
        LogLineList = new ObservableCollection<LogLine>();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<LogLine> logLineList;
    public ObservableCollection<LogLine> LogLineList
    {
        get { return logLineList; }
        set { logLineList = value; }
    }
}

public class ControllerA : ControllerMain
{
    public ControllerA() { }
    // More stuff here
}

public class ControllerB : ControllerMain
{
    public ControllerB() { }
    // More stuff here
}
```

As you can guess `ControllerA` is intended to hold logs of `TypeA`, and associated properties and methods unique to those logs. Same goes for `TypeB` logs.

In my `ViewModel`, I have instances of each of the classes above like so, and at application load I read log data and store in appropriate class object.

```
    public ControllerMain COMMON_LOG { get; set; }
    public ControllerA A_LOG { get; set; }
    public ControllerB B_LOG { get; set; }

    public ViewModelMain()
    {
        isAType = true;
        ClickCommand = new CustomCommand(ClickCmd, CanClickCmd);

        A_LOG = new ControllerA
        {
            // This simulates reading logs from files - done only once
            LogLineList = DataService.GetAData()
        };
        B_LOG = new ControllerB
        {
            // This simulates reading logs from files - done only once
            LogLineList = DataService.GetBData()
        };

        // This simulates switching to already loaded logs.
        // When I do this the log lines don't change, but I want to refresh the datagrid and display correct info.
        LoadAppropriateLog();
    }

    private void LoadAppropriateLog()
    {
        if (isAType)
        {
            COMMON_LOG = A_LOG;
            isAType = false;
        }
        else
        {
            COMMON_LOG = B_LOG;
            isAType = true;
        }
    }
```

My `View` binds to the `COMMON_LOG` instance like below:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="0" Margin="5"
          Name="dgLogs"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader"
          ItemsSource="{Binding COMMON_LOG.LogLineList}">
```

Then at the click of a button, I call the above `LoadAppropriateLog()` method, so it will simply assign the instance of appropriate type to `COMMON_LOG` which is the instance I've used to data bind.

The problem is that when I do so, since the actual data in each instance's `LogLineList` doesn't change, the `DataGrid` doesn't automatically update to reflect my choice of logs.

Is there a way to manually refresh the `DataGrid` from my `ViewModel` after every time I switch the type of log?

If you'd like to run the project and see, here's a download link:

[Download the VS Project](https://bitbucket.org/sachintha81/publicdownloads/downloads/)

Comment: `COMMON_LOG` should be a property viewmodel: Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise `PropertyChanged` when you change the value of `LogLineList`. That's what you do in WPF when the value of a bound property changes. It's easy and simple and it works.

Comment: Do you mean `ControllerMain` should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise `PropertyChanged` on `LogLineList`? Sorry I should have mentioned that I tried that, but didn't change anything.

Comment: OK noticed the edited comment. Let me try, thanks!

Comment: Wait, you're changing the value of `COMMON_LOG` instead? Raise `PropertyChanged` for that, then. Make all your viewmodels actual viewmodels, implement INPC property, and they all just work. Obviously, if you create a `ControllerA` and never change the value of its `LogLineList` property, raising `PropertyChanged` in the setter for `LogLineList` will have no effect. `LogLineList` should either raise `PropertyChanged`, or else have a private setter and only be set in the constructor or something.

Comment: No, I had earlier tried to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise `PropertyChanged` on the `LogLineList` in `ControllerMain`. But now when you pointed out it should be the `COMMON_LOG` it all makes sense. Tried it and works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: If you can please post the above comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're binding to a property of a class in XAML, either

1. The property should never change its value after a binding would first see it, and should usually be readonly just to avoid mishaps -- or
2. The class should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and the property should raise `PropertyChanged` in its setter.

In your case, you're changing the value of `COMMON_LOG`, and you're never changing the value of its `LogLineList`.

tl;dr: **So your main viewmodel needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and raise `PropertyChanged` in the setter for `COMMON_LOG`.** Anything that doesn't do those things isn't a viewmodel.

`LogLineList` being an `ObservableCollection` won't accomplish anything: What that class does is raise notifications when items are added, removed or replaced. That doesn't happen at any time after the binding sees it. Those instances of `ObservableCollection` don't even know that the main viewmodel even exists, so they certainly can't be expected to raise notification events when its properties change. Nor should they: Everybody is responsible for exactly his own notifications.

In fact, if you've made a design decision that those collections never change after initialization, use `ReadOnlyCollection` instead of `ObservableCollection`. Creating one is easy: Call `List<T>.AsReadOnly<T>()`. For any `IEnumerable<T>`, just call `e.ToList().AsReadOnly()`. `ObservableCollection` signals "you can add stuff to this". But nobody should. So don't give them ideas.

Comment: thanks for the lengthy explanation and some handy tips!